# Letter to GPA Conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a NaN return when I convert my letter input to number and then pass it to another function that totals and averages them. Is there a problem with my conversion function or the way I am calling the function?

```
function CalcGPA(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j) {
    var initial = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j;
    var total = initial / 10;
    return total;
}

function Convert(z) {
    var x = z.toString().toUpperCase();
    switch (x.value) {
        case "A":
            return 4.0;
        case "A-":
            return 3.67;
        case "B+":
            return 3.33;
        case "B":
            return 3.0;
        case "B-":
            return 2.67;
        case "C+":
            return 2.33;
        case "C":
            return 2.0;
        case "C-":
            return 1.7;
        case "D+":
            return 1.3;
        case "D":
            return 1.0;
        case "F":
            return 0;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var input2 = $('[name="grade1"],[name="grade2"],[name="grade3"],[name="grade4"],[name="grade5"],[name="grade6"],[name="grade7"],[name="grade8"],[name="grade9"],[name="grade10"],[name="grade11"]');

    input2.keyup(function () {
        var total2;
        Convert((input2[0]));
        Convert((input2[1]));
        Convert((input2[2]));
        Convert((input2[3]));
        Convert((input2[4]));
        Convert((input2[5]));
        Convert((input2[6]));
        Convert((input2[7]));
        Convert((input2[8]));
        Convert((input2[9]));
        total2 = CalcGPA(input2[0], input2[1], input2[2], input2[3], input2[4], input2[5], input2[6], input2[7], input2[8], input2[9]);
        total2.toFixed(2);
        $(input2[10]).val(total2);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your question:**

You are not storing the value of your `Convert()` calls anywhere, so when you call `CalcGPA()`, you are just sending the original letter grades into the function.

**To make your code better:**

I would also strongly recommend that you rethink the way you are collecting values from the various input fields and using them within your calculations.

For example, I would start by applying a common class across the inputs.  That way there could be 1 input or 20 inputs, and you could code to handle anything.

Let's say I give each input a class name of `gradeLetterInput`

Then you might be able to rewrite the `$(document).ready()` and `CalcGPA()` functions like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // get collection of inputs
    var $gradeLetterInputs = $('.gradeLetterInput');
    var gpaValues = $.map($gradeLetterInputs, function($item, idx) {
        return Convert($item.val());
    });
    var gpaAvg = CalcGPA(gpaValues);
    // not shown place avg GPA on DOM somwhere
}

function CalcGPA(arr) {
    var total = 0;
    var count = arr.length;
    for (i=0;i<count;i++) {
        total += arr[i];
    }
    return total/count;
}
```

Anytime you see yourself relying on id's or input names like `something#` or adding a bunch of parameters to a function call for a set of similar items, you should recognize this as an anti-pattern and try to think about how you can refactor your code to eliminate such usage.

Answer (score 0):

Call CalcGPA on the value obtained by running Convert() on the array elements. Alternatively, store the 'Converted' values to temporary variables, and then call CalcGPA with them as arguments. Something like this -

```
function CalcGPA(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j) {
    var initial = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j;
    var total = initial / 10;
    return total;
}

function Convert(z) {
    var x = z.toString().toUpperCase();
    switch (x.value) {
        case "A":
            return 4.0;
        case "A-":
            return 3.67;
        case "B+":
            return 3.33;
        case "B":
            return 3.0;
        case "B-":
            return 2.67;
        case "C+":
            return 2.33;
        case "C":
            return 2.0;
        case "C-":
            return 1.7;
        case "D+":
            return 1.3;
        case "D":
            return 1.0;
        case "F":
            return 0;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var input2 = $('[name="grade1"],[name="grade2"],[name="grade3"],[name="grade4"],[name="grade5"],[name="grade6"],[name="grade7"],[name="grade8"],[name="grade9"],[name="grade10"],[name="grade11"]');

    input2.keyup(function () {
        var total2;
        total2 = CalcGPA(Convert(input2[0]), Convert(input2[1]), Convert(input2[2]), Convert(input2[3]), Convert(input2[4]), Convert(input2[5]), Convert(input2[6]), Convert(input2[7]), Convert(input2[8]), Convert(input2[9]));
        total2.toFixed(2);
        $(input2[10]).val(total2);
    });
});
```